How to recovery previous data after reinstalling windows 11?
I asked a technician in my city to fix an error on my laptop, without knowing he performed a Windows reinstall which caused all my data to be lost. I have searched for windows.old on drive C: and I can't found it, When I asked about windows.old to him, he said windows.old folder only appears if you reset the laptop, and if you reinstall Windows, all previous data will be formatted.
I've tried several data recovery applications but had no luck. Is there any other way?

Unlikely, sorry. But the rule is simple: stop doing anything. // While it won't help with recovery, you could sue the technician. In many jurisdictions, this could be viewed as computer sabotage.

The technician is indeed correct about when Windows.old is created. If they choose to perform a clean install of Windows, then your data is deleted, and then Windows is reinstalled. The chances of data recovery when that amount of data is overwritten are very low.
